# Get details of days of week using fullcalender

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to get a detail (only date of week) of days of a particular week using **fullCalender** control.

I am getting detail of particular day only but i want a detail of whole 7 days of particular week. If I change week from 18 to 15 then data should be change.

Comment: Can you add a code sample? I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Do you want to show a week only? Or do you want to dynamically fetch events when you switch weeks? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want only two value. one is Starting day of week and second is ending day of week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the start-/enddates for a particular week you can use the `viewRender` callback to retrieve the information.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    viewRender: function(view, e){
        console.log(view.start, view.end);
    }
});
```

This code will log the start & enddates in console when you change weeks.